# angular AppComponent loads after sub component

Tags: angular, module, load, sequence

I load data in AppComponent

and then refer to this data in people.component

But people.component loads first.

AppComponent

```
  ngOnInit() {
     pre: this.getPeople();
  }

  getPeople(): any {
     this.getDATA(this.URL)
       .subscribe(people => { 
           this.people = people,
           console.log(people[0]);
       });
  }
```

people.component

```
ngOnInit() {
    pre: this.people = this.appData.people;
    this.getPeople();
 }

 getPeople(): any {
    console.log("people.component getPeople()");
 }
```

The console display "people.component getPeople()" before it displays the first element of the people array.

So, I can't leverage the people array in the people component.

Any ideas on how to get the AppComponent to run before the people.component?

Comment: I have a question. What's this `pre` thing going on in your code? I haven't seen anything like that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `appData` that you have is a dependency that you've injected in your `PeopleComponent` to get the data that `AppComponent` is getting from some REST API. It's a shared service that you've created to pass data between `AppComponent` and `PeopleComponent`. But they're having a Parent-Child relationship, you can simply pass data between them using an `@Input` property. So I'm not sure why you're doing that using a Shared Service.

Assuming from your OP, `PeopleComponent` is a child to the `AppComponent`, so you can simply pass `people` as an `@Input()` property to the `PeopleComponent`.

Just add this in the app.component.html:

```
...
<app-people [people]="people"></app-people>
...
```

And now define an `@Input` property in your PeopleComponent. Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people',
  templateUrl: './people.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people.component.css']
})
export class PeopleComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() people: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    pre: this.people = this.people;
    this.getPeople();
  }

  getPeople(): any {
    console.log("people.component getPeople()");
  }

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qaqzms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpeople%2Fpeople.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I currently have
```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```
I tried adding the @Input into the Router module but with no success. 
If I add the <app-people... to app.component.html - I get two iterations of the people component.html (because it is called by the Router module.  

I also have another module which uses the people data, and am hesitant to put in 
```
<app-maps [people]="people>
```
because the maps are off office locations and relative to a given person, so not displayed except when someone is looking for a specific person's location.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the PeopleComponent is the child of the AppComponent, and that it has an associated template, one could use the async pipe to pass data into an input property.

## app.component.ts

```
people$: Array<People>;

ngOnInit(): {
    this.people$ = this.getDATA(this.URL);
}
```

## app.component.html

```
<app-people *ngIf="people$ | async as people" [people]="people"></app-people>
```

## people.component.ts

```
@Input() people: Array<People>;

[...remaining code elided...]
```